Define lifetime for associative type without lifetime bound
I am implementing FromStr for a type and for the error I want to return the passed &str inside a wrapper struct. However, this requires the the struct to have a lifetime bound for the &str but that will cause errors inside FromStr since its associative type Err does not have any lifetime bounds and cannot be modified either. Lastly, it's not possible to add a lifetime bound to the impl since the lifetime does not get constrained by anything, at least in the ways I have tried. So, how can I squeeze in my wrapper into the associative type?
For more context, here are the definitions:
pub enum RarityTag {
    // ...
}

pub struct ParseRarityTagError<'a>(&'a str);

impl FromStr for RarityTag {
    type Err = ParseRarityTagError<'a>;

    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        match s {
            // ...
            rest => Err(ParseRarityTagError(rest)),
        }
    }
}


You cannot return an error with a lifetime bound to the string that FromStr::from_str gives you. The trait was not designed for it. It would have to define Err a generic associated type with a lifetime parameter in order to support that, but it doesn't.
You need either a different error scheme that doesn't rely on the lifetime or use an inherent method / free function and not the FromStr trait.

Allocating a String on Err is probably perfectly fine. It's not ideal but if you don't expect to be going down that path too often then you should go for it. You can always change it later.

@kalkronline Yeah I'll have to do that for now. Unfortunately it's going to be used to parse components of a somewhat large file, but I guess I'll have to look for something more dedicated when optimizing for performance later on.
Thanks for the quick reply @kmdreko!
